# a single word for "lack of accountability?"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

What is a single word for "lack of accountability?"

I'm thinking *unorganised*, but something is telling me that I'm trying to describe something else when I use that word.

Answer (score 1):

I might think of *dereliction* (of duty).

**[dereliction](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/dereliction)** (ODOL)
**2** (**dereliction of duty**) The shameful failure to fulfil one's obligations.

Answer (score 0):

One obvious option would be *unaccountability*; but without more context it is not possible to decide what the best one would be.

Here is an [article in the Marine Pollution Bulletin](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0025326X18300523) that uses the word in its headline talking about the lack of accountability for spillage of plastic pellets into waterways.

And here is [another one](https://realsport101.com/news/sports/football/atletico-madrid-griezmanns-unaccountability-could-ruin-football/) about a misbehaving footballer from the RealSport website.

Answer (score 0):

[**Freewheeling**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/freewheeling)

> free and loose in form or manner: such as
>
> a : heedless of social norms or niceties · the raider style of his *freewheeling* father —Garry Wills
>
> b : not repressed or restrained · *freewheeling* promiscuity · a *freewheeling* competitive spirit
>
> c : not bound by formal rules, procedures, or guidelines · a *freewheeling* investigation
>
> d : loose and undisciplined : not defensive · a *freewheeling* style of hockey

Answer (score 0):

The first word that came to mind as a broad cover for "a lack of accountability" is *apathy*. "Apathy suggests a puzzling or deplorable inertness or lack of passion,..." [Apathy: Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/apathy)